# how to create list of uniques using list comprehension

Tags: python

I've wrote this code

```
def rec_offspring(n,offspring):

    if n == 1:
        return [[sprng] for sprng in offspring]
    else:
        return [[sprng1] for sprng1 in offspring] +\
        [sprng2 for sprng2 in rec_offspring(n-1,offspring)]
```

how can i change it so it will return list of uniqes?

for example:

```
rec_offspring(3,[1,2,3])
```

should return:

```
[[2,3,1],[3,2,1],[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,1,3]
```

Comment: [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)?

Comment: If you say "unique" you should think `set`, not `list`. But in this case there seems to be a more specific answer.

Comment: What is the code supposed to be doing originally?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a recursive function you can use backtracking to create the permutations:

```
def permute(a, i, out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = []
    if i == len(a):
        out.append(a)
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(a)):
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
            permute(a, i + 1,out)
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    return out
print(permute([1,2,3],0))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```